# Shellscript - read blockwise

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I was wondering if it's possible to read from a file blockwise until a specific delimiter (i.e. a certain string or something), not linewise (as 'read' would do).

input.txt contains:

```
text1
text2
NEXT
text3
NEXT
text4
text5
```

Each text-section should be saved in a certain single file (text1+text2 // text3 // text4+text5)

I played around a bit with editing the IFS but had no success unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gnu-awk` with custom record separator:

```
awk -v RS='\nNEXT\n' '{sub(/\n$/, ""); print "<" $0 ">"}' file
<text1
text2>
<text3>
<text4
text5>
```

Each block in `<...>` is a single record.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the first help! Is there are more simple way to achive this? and how is each single record saved to a single file?

Comment: e.g. you can just use: `awk -v RS='\nNEXT\n' '{sub(/\n$/, ""); print $0 > "file" NR }' file`

Comment: file1 file2 file3 would be ok, i'm going to try this

Comment: That should work for you as I've tested it, let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: works so far. This line gives me output files named 1 2 and 3. Can I somehow change this to custom names like file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt? I assume the numbering is coming from the NR after the "file" statement?

Comment: Yes sure that also be done: `awk -v RS='\nNEXT\n' '{sub(/\n$/, ""); print $0 > "file" NR ".txt" }' file` and yes `NR` gives us the numbers

Comment: Well, this works out almost perfecty :)
the only problem is that  
text1  <br/>
text2  
appears as text1text2 (no linebreak or space) in the output file and the delimiter (NEXT) is also directed into the last output file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77512/discussion-between-user3322838-and-anubhava).

Comment: I was offline and missed your chat invitation. If you edit your question with the input data to recreate the problem I will look into it and suggest you a fix.

Comment: Change `print $0 > "file" NR ".txt"` to `print > ("file" NR ".txt")` for brevity and, much more importantly, portability. The only way that `NEXT` is appearing in the output is if it's not surrounded by newlines or you are not using GNU awk.